# What's difference between float, double and decimal in sql?

Tags: mysql, database, currency, sqldatatypes

I was asked to add a column containg the bonuses of salary of employees, examples of this values were give such as: 1099.99 or 2.00. Task also asked me to add appropriate data type but I was confused which one to use.

I tried using both double and float and couldn't differenciate between the results. So, help me choose appropriate datatype.

Comment: Floating point numbers (double,float) are for things like dimensions, time, weights, … decimal is for things like currency related such as price, salary, …

Comment: Or in other words if it is fine that something like 0.1 + 0.2 is 0.2999999999 you use floating point but if 0.1 + 0.2 has to be exactly 0.3 you use decimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"No difference"?  That was lucky.

Use `DECIMAL(m,n)` for money.  For many currencies, `DECIMAL(m,2)`, where `m` is big enough so that you won't overflow even when the CEO gets a big raise.   DECIMAL`occupies _approximately_ m/2 bytes.  1 billion dollars or Euros needs`(11,2)` and takes 5 bytes.

`FLOAT` and `DOUBLE` are for measurements.  `FLOAT` occupies 4 bytes and has about 7 significant digits -- plenty for temperature, speed, height, etc.
DOUBLE` (8 bytes) gives you about 16 significant digits; it may be needed from some very precise scientific research.

Latitude and Longitude -- `FLOAT` is precise though to distinguish two vehicles on the road, but not to distinguish two people embracing.  See also
https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng#representation_choices

For various reasons (many not listed here), none of the representations can be trusted to *round* "correctly" according to banking rules when multiplying or dividing.  Addition of dollars and cents *will* be exact with `DECIMAl`.

Answer (score 1):

Computer scientist Brian Kernighan wrote:

> 10.0 times 0.1 is hardly ever 1.0.

`FLOAT` and `DOUBLE` are both IEEE 754 format values. They store a wide range of floating-point value, including very small or very large values, but they have the disadvantage that they have rounding errors.

For examples and details on that, read:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-float.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

`FLOAT` stores 32 bits and `DOUBLE` stores 64 bits. This just means you can store more significant digits with a `DOUBLE`, but it still has the same rounding behavior.

These data types are good for scientific measurements like temperature, where the difference between 39 degrees and 38.999999997 degrees won't make a significant difference, especially if you're only doing things like averages or standard deviations.

Because of the rounding behavior, `FLOAT` and `DOUBLE` should never be used to store values of currency.

For currency values (e.g. the salaries you need to store), use `DECIMAL`.

`DECIMAL` and `NUMERIC` are exact scaled numerics. You define a column with a specific number of digits, and a specific number of digits to the right of the decimal point. There are no rounding problems; values you store come right back out exactly as you stored them. You can search the data for specific values.

`DECIMAL` and `NUMERIC` are synonyms. There's no difference. In fact, if you use `NUMERIC` as the type, MySQL silently replaces it with `DECIMAL`.

You may also like to read the chapter "Rounding Errors" in my book, [SQL Antipatterns, Volume 1: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming](https://pragprog.com/titles/bksap1/sql-antipatterns-volume-1/).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to the [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html), we have the next diferences:

- FLOAT - Floating-Point Types (Approximate Value), uses four bytes
- DOUBLE - Floating-Point Types (Approximate Value), uses eight bytes
- DECIMAL - Fixed-Point Types (Exact Value)

You can ask about differences between floating and fixed datatypes, but this is not so easy to describe, try to read the same official documentation, or [this article](https://matthew-brett.github.io/teaching/floating_error.html), for example.